# What is the relation between basis vectors of a vector space to those of its subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

From [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081025080700AAqpyd4) question:

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space with dimension $6$. Let A and B be subspaces of V with dimensions 4 and 5 respectively. What are the possible values for the dimension of A intersection B?

The reasoning given in the answer:

> The best way is to look at the basis. Any basis for $A$ consists of $4$ elements, say $\{a, b, c, d\}$. Suppose that $e, f$ are vectors of $V$ such that $\{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$ span the whole $V$. **Since $B$ has dim $5$, exactly five elements of $\{a, b, c, d, e, f\}$ are in $B$**.

$\ldots$

---

The part in bold bothers me. Why is it necessary that *any* basis for $B$ *must* contain elements from basis of $V$ ?

More generally, what is the relation between basis vectors of a vector space to those of its subspace?

Comment: You are right to be worried. It's wrong. None of the basis vectors need to lie in $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example: $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, with basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.  Let $B=Span((1,1))$, a diagonal line.  Neither basis vector from $V$ is in $B$.

In short, the bold statement is incorrect.  Try Math.SE next time instead of Yahoo answers.

---

Hint for question that led to all this:  Given finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and subspaces $A,B$, we have $$\dim(A)+\dim(B)=\dim(A+B)+\dim(A\cap B)$$

Comment: In that case, would the correct answer to the original question be : any of $0,1,2,3,4$ ?

Comment: @curryage No, either $3$ or $4$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Using the formula provided by vadim123, that becomes possible when $dim(A+B)$ is $4$ or $5$, which makes sense. Is there a good online reference where I can read up more specifically on such relationships between subspaces ?

Comment: @curryage When $\dim (A+B)$ is $6$ or $5$. I don't know any online references, but every introductory book on linear algebra should help getting familiar with such relations.